# How to implement texturing over a model using pycollada?

Tags: python-2.7, texture-mapping, collada

I am developing a python script which will be able to generate .DAE (COLLADA) files along with the associated KML files for developing 3D models of buildings. I have the street images of the buildings. By street images, I mean the front face image of each building. I need to put these images as a texture over their respective building models. I am unable to find suitable method by which I can do this using python. Till now, I have succeeded in generating blank cubes or cuboids which can be positioned over the map representing the buildings. I need to put the image as a texture on the front plane of these models taking the image as an input.
Kindly help.

Comment: please post some of your codes..!! I Will ask BABA..

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to post the code, given that you are aware about COLLADA files. You can be able to help me with the help of pseudo codes if you want to. Check your inbox though, I've shared the gist with you.